# I got error in this code i convert java script code in c#

Tags: c#

I write code in C# but got an error.

I try it online write code and got error in this code

```
using System;

public class Program
{
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string t= "0";
            string g="0";
            string h;

            int tt =Int32.Parse(t);

            t = Console.ReadLine();
            g = Console.ReadLine();

            if (t = 7, g = 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(t=7);
                Console.WriteLine(g=1);
                Console.WriteLine(h=);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");}
            }
        }
}
```

I got error here :

```
 if (t = 7, g = 1)
```

I want the output t=7,g=1,h=" but got error

I convert the string to int but when I use if statement, then i got error

Comment: And **which error** did you get? What was the original javascript? I suspect it was not using comma there.

Comment: That's just plain **invalid** C# code - any beginner's tutorial should teach you how to properly combine two boolean checks:  `if (t = 7  && g = 1) { ..... }`

Comment: `if (t == 7 && g == 1)`? If `t` equals to `7` *and* `g` equals to `1` then...

Comment: Note that `=` is assignment in C#, `==` is comparison, and `Console.WriteLine(<assignment>)` will output the value of the assignment (7 or 1), and if you replaced assignment with comparison, you'd get true or false as output.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you want the output of the program to be, and not just "I got an error".

Comment: C# is strong typed, and you must declare each variable with its exact type. For example, for ReadLine, t and g must be string. By the way, you cannot compare a string an a number: a conversion must be made somewhere. Finally, beware the single equal sign inside the WiteLine: a single one means assignment, if you mean equality type it twice. As JavaScript, however.

Comment: i do it but there is error in t=7 they not convert the string into int

Comment: In order to convert javascript code to C#, you need to know both. This question is too broad for a Q&A format.

Comment: when i replace = with == in writeline line then there is error in starting parentheses Console.WriteLine(t=7) that befor t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have converted `JavaScript`code to `C#`. So, you need to make some changes in code as, `C#` is strictly Typed language and `JavaScript` is not.

If you really want your variables to `String`, change the `if` condition as :

```
    if (t == "7" && g == "1") //Add && operator between two condition and wrap values in double quote("")
    {
        //Add any assignment if you want
        Console.WriteLine(t); // remove assignment
        Console.WriteLine(g); // remove assignment
        Console.WriteLine(h); // remove assignment
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the if statement you cant give value to a variable. In this case you are trying to add a new value to valiable **t** (one "=" means assignment). If you want to check if **t**'s value equals to 7 then you need to use line this: `if(t == "7")`. Because t is a string variable it cant be equal to an int (7) value. If you want to make an end statement your code will look like this: `if(t == "7" && g == "1")`.
Finally if you want to write out the value of the variabley sou can use the followings depending your .net version:

- `Console.WriteLine($"t = {t}");`
- `Console.WriteLine(String.Format("t = {0}", t));`
- `Console.WriteLine("t = " + t);`

I hope it helped!